Группировка данных с использованием Query
У меня есть две таблицы База и Отчет. База содержит данные по результатам проверки (1 колонка – одна проверка), для простоты возьмем две строки дата проверки и набранный балл.
Следует вывести результаты в таблицу Отчет следующим образом:

все данные сведены по месяцам (при этом балл за месяц считаем как среднее)
при необходимости можем развернуть месяц до проверок.

Я знаю, что такое можно сделать с помощью сводной таблицы, но для этого нужно в таблицу Отчет на отдельный лист передать результаты (сырье для сводной) – а этого делать не хочется.
Второй вариант использовать Query и Importrange, но здесь теряется удобство сводных таблиц, так как в  Query мы можем группировать или по проверкам или по месяцам (не можем развернуть 1 конкретный месяц).
Возможно сможете посоветовать, как использовать сводную и при этом не переносить данные из таблицы База или, как сделать в Query группировку как в сводной

Вы можете добавить сводную таблицу в любую ячейку на любой лист, даже на лист, где хранится "сырье" для сводной таблицы. Не вижу сложностей для её создания.
Если же вам необходимо хранить данные в "Базе", а сводную иметь в "Отчёте" вы можете на в "Отчёте" на отдельный лист направлять данные через IMPORTRANGE, а сам лист заблокировать и скрыть (здесь не понимаю почему не хочется передавать данные, если из соображений доступа к данным - заблокируйте лист и скройте его).
